# WebRequest with proxy throwing HTTP 405 method not allowed error

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy

I'm making simple HTTP GET request to website using `WebRequest`. When I add proxy details,getting HTTP 405 method not allowed error.

Below is my code:

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
//WebProxy prr = new WebProxy();

WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("xxxxx");

req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

req.Method = "GET";
req.Proxy = proxy;
HttpWebResponse resp=req.GetResponse();
```

"xxxx" is our org proxy URL.

It's working fine **WITHOUT** proxy, but I need to make it to work with proxy details.

Am I missing anything?.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the proxy you may need to mention the port also. See the code below

```
string ipAddrs= "proxy ip ";
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ipAddrs,3128);
```

default proxy port number is 3128

Comment: I've tried with port, now it's saying "The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'"  :(

Comment: @malkam:  if you are using proxy url then use the below code

`WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyurl:3128");`

Comment: It's working fine now after correcting Proxy Ip Address. thanks for your help :)